# JavaFX: Hardcode a "Ctrl+C" keypress

Tags: java, javafx, clipboard

I have a JavaFX application that has various `TextField` widgets in the main frame. I have a `MenuBar` that includes the `MenuItem` objects "Copy" and "Paste" like a standard production application would have. Since any or none of the various `TextField` objects could be selected at any given time, it seems easier to just hardcode a "Ctrl+C" or "Ctrl+V" key press in the `setOnAction` events of the "Copy" and "Paste" `MenuItem` objects rather than use a `Clipboard` object and loop iterating through all `TextFields` to find the highlighted text (if any).

Is there a way to hardcode this key press action in Java? I looked into the `KeyCombination` class but it does not actually trigger the action described by the given key combination.

Comment: Hardcode a `Ctrl+C` Key press??? Iterate through the fields? Could you explain what you mean by that??? (Firing a key event yourself on a descendant node of the `TextField` or something like this???)

Comment: I think I explained the problem pretty well but here is the pseudocode: `Clipboard.execute("Ctrl+C")`. And yes, the alternative solution is to put all `TextField` objects in an array, iterate through the array looking for the first `TextField` with a `getSelected()` property that is true.

Comment: Text field doesn't have a `getSelected()` method. Are you referring to having the focus?

Comment: I believe `getSelectedText()` is the `TextField` method that will return highlighted text

Comment: I was just wondering if I can just trigger Ctrl+C as a command

Comment: But that will return the selected text in any of your text fields. What are you wanting to do if multiple text fields have text selected? This problem doesn't seem to be well defined or carefully thought through.

Comment: I've set it up so that only one `TextField` can have highlighted text at any given time.

Comment: Well in the code that sets that up, presumably it would be really easy to put that particular text field into a variable somewhere. It's always better just to encapsulate your logic than to manually fire events on controls (you'd still need to know which text field you wanted to fire the Ctrl-C keystroke on anyway...)

Comment: After all, if the user presses Ctrl-C, the key event is fired on the text field with the keyboard focus. Typically (in any application I use) that is the behavior of a menu item too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think by "Since any or none of the various `TextField` objects could be selected at any given time" you are referring to which (if any) text field has the keyboard focus.

You can easily get this information from the scene: just do

```
Node focusOwner = scene.getFocusOwner();
if (focusOwner instanceof TextField) {
    TextField textField = (TextField) focusOwner ;
    String selectedText = textField.getSelectedText();
    // ...
}
```

Note also that `TextInputControl` defines a `copy()` method that copies the selected text to the system clipboard. (Similarly, there's a `paste()` method too.) So you can leverage those to make the functionality easy.

Here's a SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FocusMenuTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        VBox textFields = new VBox(5, new TextField("One"), new TextField("Two"), new TextField("Three"));
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        Menu edit = new Menu("Edit");
        MenuItem copy = new MenuItem("Copy");

        copy.setOnAction(e -> {
            Node focusOwner = menuBar.getScene().getFocusOwner();
            if (focusOwner instanceof TextInputControl) {
                ((TextInputControl)focusOwner).copy();
            }
        });     

        MenuItem paste = new MenuItem("Paste");
        paste.setOnAction(e -> {
            Node focusOwner = menuBar.getScene().getFocusOwner();
            if (focusOwner instanceof TextInputControl) {
                ((TextInputControl)focusOwner).paste();
            }
        });

        menuBar.getMenus().add(edit);
        edit.getItems().addAll(copy, paste);
        root.setCenter(textFields);
        root.setTop(menuBar);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);


        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```